# Using powershell to determine if multiple duplicates of a process is running (new to powershell)

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I've been struggling trying to find the proper way to write this batch script to run in powershell. Im basically wanting powershell to look for a certain process that is running and if its found running count the number of said processes are running and if that number is greater than 1 but less than 50 to then write count out to a file. This is what I have so far..

```
@echo off

Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -Command "@(Get-Process | ? { $_.ProcessName -eq "<process name>" }).Count       | Out-File c:\dds.txt"
```

After .Count I have no clue what to put (thats if it even goes after the .Count. I'm very new to powershell and scripting at that and at this point have spent so much time trying different things, I thought that asking here would be the best thing I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you simply want the count stored in c:\dds.txt if it's between 2 and 49.

You can provide multiple commands separated by `;` on the same line.

I modified the code to save the count of the result in a variable, then I simply evaluate that variable with `if ($count -gt 1 -and $count -lt 50)`.

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -Command "$count = @(Get-Process | ? { $_.ProcessName -eq 'chrome' }).Count; if ($count -gt 1 -and $count -lt 50){ $count | Out-File c:\dds.txt}"
```